# share a struct throughout multiple thread

Tags: c, multithreading, irc

i am writing a small IRC program in C.I'm using thread to handle multiple clients,
and i use a chained list to store the fd of each client.So if a client send a message, it will be written on the fd of the others.

I'm not sure this is the best way to do, could you give me some advice ???

Plus, in this way, i need to share the struct (that contains the file descriptior of each clients) throughout the thread, so if there is an update in a thread, it will update the struc for the others.I'm wondering how i could do this, how could i share that struct ??

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Which O/S are you writing for?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your design it's very difficult to comment on whether your linked list of FDs is appropriate.

In terms of sharing a struct of data between threads there is nothing you need to do. Threads share memory space so anything visible in one thread will be visible in another. Your only risk is that you have multiple threads modifying the struct at one time, something you protect against by using a mutex (mutual exclusion semaphore).

Since you're on Linux I'm assuming you're using POSIX Threads ([pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)) in which case you'll need to look at the [pthread_mutex_](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes) functions.

Comment: ok so i don't need to do anything about the shared struct thanx.But how would you write a message to a list of fd without a linked list ???

Comment: Well, each thread could hold its own copy of the list and then message the other threads as it needed. Or you could have a master thread that knows about all the other threads and handles getting the data in and out from them all. Or you could avoid threads entirely, which may make the task neater. There's a LOT of ways of solving your problem, but which is best is rather dependent on what you're trying to achieve :-)

Comment: well i just want to create an irc with 2 channel, when a user A send a message, the message is send to everyone in the same channel.

Comment: ok thank you.Last question, do you know if i can use SDL to make the client ? (just for the display)

Answer (score 0):

In your setup, I would use:

- one input queue per channel,
- one output queue per client.

Whenever a client thread receives a message, it posts it to the channel thread. When a channel receives a new post, it reposts it to all the clients. Each channel and client can be represented as a `struct`, which may be handled then by the threads (with one or more clients or channel per thread).

All queues are simple linked lists protected using a `pthread_mutex_t`. When a function needs to access them, it locks the queue, add the message, and unlock.

- [pthread_mutex_create](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_create)
- [pthread_mutex_lock](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock)
- [pthread_mutex_unlock](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_unlock)